# What is causing Hibernate to execute an update statement when I render an image?

Tags: hibernate, grails, render

I have a controller action:

```
def showFormImage() {
    def studyId = params.studyId
    def imageInstance = Image?.findByStudyIdAndSequence(studyId, params.sequence)

    byte[] image = imageInstance?.imageData
    render file: image,
           contentType: "image/jpeg"
}
```

I call the action by this line of jQuery:

```
$('#imageToReview').attr('src', "/forms/imageManagement/showFormImage?studyId=" + data.studyId + "&sequence=1&timestamp=" + new Date());
```

I have this error in my stack trace:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ... Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Forms.Image'.
Message: could not update: [...]; SQL [/* update ...Image */ update Forms.Image set DateUploaded=?, FileName=?, ImageData=?, Sequence=? where StudyID=?]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not update: [...Image#...]
```

I enabled SQL Logging and notice that an update request is being made to my Image table:

```
Hibernate: 
/* update
    forms.Image */ update
        Forms.Image 
    set
        DateUploaded=?,
        FileName=?,
        ImageData=?,
        Sequence=? 
    where
        StudyID=?
```

What is causing hibernate to execute the update request on my Image table? I am baffled. The images do get pulled into my web page, so my code is working OK. I have two other similar actions which pull images from different tables. These also work correctly, but I do not get this error in the logs. I cannot seem to find any other references to this issue on the web.

UPDATE:

The primary key for the Image class is composite. studyId and sequence.

The Image class needed updating to:

```
class Image implements Serializable {
    ...
    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!other instanceof Image) {
            return false
        }
        other.studyId ==studyId &&
        other.sequence == sequence
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
       builder.append studyId
       builder.append sequence
    }
    ...
    static mapping = {
    ...
    id    composite: [studyId, sequence]
    ...
 }
```

The error has gone. So I can no longer post the complete stack trace. However, the update statement is still there in the SQL logging. Now it is a question of technical curiosity only.

Comment: Having a bit longer look at the problem I think it is a smoke screen. The only way you can get this MS SQL error is when you try to insert a row with a primary key value that is already in the table. So an update can't cause the error.

Comment: Hi, I have added a little bit more from the stack trace. As you can see the error is definitely related to the update statement.

Comment: Is the primary key of the Image table one of the `DateUploaded `,`FileName `, `ImageData ` or `Sequence `? If so then you have a problem if not then the error message is not caused by the update.

Comment: Don't add "a little bit more". Add the **complete** stack trace. Also, show the relevant code: the entity and the findByStudyIdAndSequence method

Comment: @defectus Thank you for putting me on the right track. I forgot that I had modified the primary key for this table. I am still getting the update though in my log, but no errors.